# I can not make insert ignore query

Tags: javascript, knex.js

How I can make `insert ignore` query with knex?

I tried:

```
knex.raw(knex('music').insert({title: service[i].Title, author: service[i].PrimaryArtistName, album: service[i].TypeAlbumName, lyrics: service[i].Lyrics}).toString().replace("insert", 'insert ignore'));
```

But it's doesn't work

Update:
its work if I add

```
.then(function (res) {
 console.log("res", res);// or another code
 });
```

But does its right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is pull request in progress to support this officially in knex APIs. I hope it gets ready to the next release https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/pull/2197.

You should never use `.toString()` to build query, since it might easily leave sql injection hole to your code especially with inserts.

It didn't do anything at first, because you never triggered the query.

Currently you could achieve the same more secure way like this:

```
const query = knex('music')
  .insert({
    title: service[i].Title, 
    author: service[i].PrimaryArtistName, 
    album: service[i].TypeAlbumName, 
    lyrics: service[i].Lyrics
  }).toSQL();

const sql = query.sql.replace("insert", 'insert ignore');
knex.raw(sql, query.bindings).then(() => console.log('insert is ready'));
```